# Certain images not getting loaded with relative path - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, relative-path, fxml, image-loading

I'm developing a portable desktop application and the UI uses certain images. My application's absolute path is: C:/Users/JP/Documents/EOL/Collection/DataCollection/src/application/

I have my fxml and main class source files in application folder(specified above) and 3 images in "images" folder inside application folder. All are .jpg files. When I reference to these files in my fxml file using relative path, 1 gets loaded while the other two doesn't.

I don't know why one specific file loads while others fails to load.

When I reference that one file in all the three locations of my fxml, it works fine. And when I reference to all the 3 different images with absolute paths, it works fine. But I'm not understanding the issue with relative paths with respect to only a few files. Can anyone help me with this?

I've also tried replacing '@' with "file:", but didn't help.

```
<ImageView fitHeight="333.0" fitWidth="450.0" opacity="0.27">
    <image>
         <Image url="@images/ht.jpg" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
<ImageView fitHeight="70.0" fitWidth="68.0" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="7.0">
    <image>
        <Image url="@images/eol.jpg" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
<ImageView fitHeight="103.0" fitWidth="162.0" layoutX="78.0" layoutY="-9.0" preserveRatio="true">
    <image>
        <Image url="@images/eol2.gif" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Are you using Scenic Builder 2.0? If so, when you open the fxml file with it, do you see the three images? If you don't, try loading them from the Inspector tab, Properties->Image, browse. Save and close, and build run the app again.

Comment: Yes. I'm using scene builder 2.0. I see all the images in scene builder but I don't see one of them when I run it from a java code. Tried loading from the inspector tab as well. No luck!

Comment: I really can't tell what's going on, without seeing your code. You could try using [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), while you run your application, and see what shows you under the `ImageView` nodes. What container are you using for them? Maybe they are loaded but behind the one you see or outside the visible scene...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to this, aparrently you need to include the full classpath of your project in the relative url.

For example if my FXML file was at the following package:

```
com/dscalzi/testproject/ui/MyFXML.fxml
```

and my image was in the following package:

```
com/dscalzi/testproject/ui/assets/myimage.png
```

The proper relative path would be:

```
<Image url="@/com/dscalzi/testproject/ui/assets/myimage.png" />
```

It appears that fxml loads images using the full classpath.